# Programmatic equivalent of Gimp's Contiguous selection tool

Tags: python, image-processing, gimp

I need to automate the analyses of many similar images which are basic lots of small blackish blobs on a somewhat homogeneous brown  background.

I have tried the find_blobs method from simpleCV but it is not accurate enough. However with gimps contiguous selection tool, also known as Magic wand, I was able to achieve much better results, in separating the background from my blobs.

My problem is that I need to automate this process, so I can't have a person clicking on each image. Any suggestion of a Python friendly library in which I can find this functionality? Is using Gimp in batch mode the only way?

Comment: Contiguous selection is very similar to a [flood or seed fill](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill) operation provided by many image editing programs. The difference, of course, is that the pixels are selected rather than having their color immediately changed. I doubt it's feasible to implement this in Python because it would be too slow, but that's basically an algorithm you could adapt to do what you seek. Gimp is open source, so in theory you could use that as an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pdb.gimp_image_select_contiguous_color` is the programatic way - in a Python plug-in - of doing the magic wand. The drawback is that you have to issue suitable starting coordinates for it to work well.
Maye repeating the process in 3 distant points of the image, and if the selection does not diverge by much in two of those, assume that to be the one you want.

The procedure does not return the selection drawable, so you have to get it by issuing
pdb.gimp_image_get_selection afterwards. You will also need to set the threshold by calling `pdb.gimp_context_set_sample_threshold` before calling it.

(My suggestion: copy it to another, new image, resize that to an 8x8pixel image, from which you can get the pixel values and compare directly against other selections made);

Comment: Thanks joão, too bad I can't do this outside of Gimp. I'll try that, maybe I can select points by color, since my images all have the same background.

Comment: You can do it outside GIMP, but with a Python plug-in in GIMP you could have  a "server-like" plug-in to open an image, run several gimp-ops on it, and save the file. It could be piloted by simple Python xml-rpc, for example - check http://docs.python.org/2/library/simplexmlrpcserver.html

Answer (score 2):

OpenCV could be the answer, [this](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/find_contours/find_contours.html) brief tutorial may help you.
In that example it uses "blur" to make the image more homogeneous, if it is not enough you could try also with [erode and dilate](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/erosion_dilatation/erosion_dilatation.html).

Those examples are in C++, but opencv python bindings are really similar to C++ interface, so you should not have any problem translating it.